# How to Filter YouTube content from an iPhone app objective-c

Tags: ios, youtube

My app on the Apple Store is rated 4+. There's a link to a video tutorial using this code:

```
-(IBAction)videoButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    // URL from safari address bar.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:YOUTUBE_VIDEO_TUTORIAL_LINK] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
}
```

It all works fine.
However, it's been rejected on the grounds that "app allows unfiltered access to YouTube, where content with mature or suggestive themes can be accessed, it should be rated 17+"

Is there anyway in the code, that this can be filtered so I can maintain the 4+ rating?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not able to host the content in your own system or possibly another content provider; YouTube takes in input in the HTTP params (Setting the rel param to 0) to not show recommended videos (However can still possibly show other videos from your channel). Apple still might not say this is a solution as there is no way to tell if one video on your channel is PG and another happens to be for example a horror game walkthrough.

Please see below in their documentation:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#rel